# Maximise network transfer speed of various applications

Tags: linux, networking, performance, file-transfer

When using `nc`, `scp`, `wget` to transfer files between 2 machines on a dedicated 2Mbps link, I get speeds between 0.5 and 1 Mbps. However, when I use `iperf -c 10.0.1.4 -t 20 -P 12` (for example) I can maximise the speed of the link (getting stable 2Mbps).

Is there a way to make single stream transfers (such as those done by `scp`) to utilise all/most of the link? Some kind of tcp settings, or iptables...?

Comment: Alex, I am curious, what was the resolution to your problem?  Did you have packet loss, or did you break up your files for parallel transfers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's admit that you're comparing apples and oranges.

`nc`, `scp` and `wget` typically transfer with a single TCP socket.  However, when you use `iperf -P 12`, you are using *twelve* parallel TCP sockets.  This is a non-trivial distinction.  The more parallel connections you have, the larger your bandwidth consumption will be.  In fact, [`speedtest.net`](http://www.speedtest.net) uses multiple parallel TCP streams to reliably measure bandwith capacity, even if your link has significant packet loss that would tank a single TCP socket; I have seen them saturate links with 1.5% loss (which would decimate throughput on a normal TCP socket).

The primary reasons for sub-optimal single-socket TCP transfers are packet loss and delay / jitter.  You need to identify and correct whether you have any ongoing packet loss through your link... I usually use [`mtr`](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) or [`winmtr`](http://winmtr.net/) for this...

```
mpenning@mpenning-T61:~$ mtr -n <destination_ip>
HOST: mpenning-T61              Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1. 10.239.84.1                0.0%    407    8.8   9.1   7.7  11.0   1.0
  2. 66.68.3.223                0.0%    407   11.5   9.2   7.1  11.5   1.3
  3. 66.68.0.8                  0.0%    407   19.9  16.7  11.2  21.4   3.5
  4. 72.179.205.58              0.0%    407   18.5  23.7  18.5  28.9   4.0
  5. 66.109.6.108               5.2%    407   16.6  17.3  15.5  20.7   1.5 <----
  6. 66.109.6.181               4.8%    407   18.2  19.1  16.8  23.6   2.3
  7. 4.59.32.21                 6.3%    407   20.5  26.1  19.5  68.2  14.9
  8. 4.69.145.195               6.4%    406   21.4  27.6  19.8  79.1  18.1
  9. <destination_ip>           6.8%    406   22.3  23.3  19.4  32.1   3.7
```

If you see a hop where you consistently loose packets over time, *and* the hops behind it are loosing packets, then you need to fix whatever is causing that packet loss.  I usually measure for at least five or ten minutes... often for hours, if I don't see the problem immediately.

The other situation is delay... you will need to quantify the problem further with specifics about the end-to-end delay as well as src/dest OS information before someone can respond to this.

So you have some choices... either:

- Figure out what is causing you to drop performance
- Break up your transfers into multiple files and transfer them in parallel (to overcome whatever factors are dropping your throughput now)